# Enabling eMMC pins as gpio's on BeagleBone Black

Tags: debian, sd-card, beaglebone

I’m trying to enable the eMMC pins (P3-P6 and P21-25 on the P8 header) as GPIO's on my BeagleBoneBlack rev C with no success. My current system runs through the micro SD card as I have disabled the corresponding eMMC line on uEnv.txt for the use of the pins.

I have tried loading the cape overlay of  [Derek Molly Device Tree](https://github.com/derekmolloy/boneDeviceTree/blob/master/overlay/DM-GPIO-Test.dts) and [cape-univ-emmc](https://github.com/beagleboard/bb.org-overlays/blob/master/src/arm/cape-univ-emmc-00A0.dts) to "/sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots" ($SLOTS) with still no success. Whilst I can compile and load the cape overlay on my device tree, when I toggle the value of the GPIO pin through "sys/class/gpio/gpioXX" the eMMc pin's voltage does not change.

Whilst previously I did get the desired result (through [Enabling all the gpio pins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635808/enable-all-gpio-pins-on-beaglebone-including-the-emmc-pins)) it was at the cost of disabling the HDMI, which in my scenario I can't afford. Can anyone please give me clues/suggestions on how I could solve this issue?

System info:

My system is running on the " [Debian 9.1 2017-08-31 4GB SD LXQT](http://debian.beagleboard.org/images/bone-debian-9.1-lxqt-armhf-2017-08-31-4gb.img.xz)" image acquired from [BBB_Image](https://beagleboard.org/latest-images)

My kernel version is: 4.9.45-ti-r57

Answer (score 0):

I am using Debian Stretch. Just un-comment below line in /boot/uEnv.txt and reboot.

```
#disable_uboot_overlay_emmc=1
```

to

```
disable_uboot_overlay_emmc=1
```

This will disable emmc and free-up all pins allocated for emmc. Note that you have run beaglebone from SD card.